# cordova 6.3.1 , How read images from OBB files using content:// in my img src tag html

Tags: cordova, crosswalk-project

I have cordova 6.3.1 and plugin crosswalk WEBVIEW https://crosswalk-project.org

We need use OBB files downloaded from our Google Play (APK  + APK APK EXPANSION FILES) downloaded as OBB (like explained here https://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html)

Some plugins like these :
https://github.com/moust/phonegap-xapkreader
https://github.com/agamemnus/cordova-plugin-xapkreader/issues/26
Are not going ok with graddle in cordova 6.3.1 and android studio 2.2.1

Here a good explanation but usin java native Android.

Somebody know if there is a cordova plugin using this idea.

Have crosswalk WEBVIEW a built in functionaliti for access OBB files, something like

Thanks in advance, please, sorry my bad English.